# Names of namespaces and model conflict

Tags: c#, namespaces, naming-conventions

[According to Microsoft guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-namespaces)

> X DO NOT use the same name for a namespace and a type in that
>   namespace.

Following that rule feels mandatory yet not that easy. To demonstrate my problem lets take an generic `Account` feature. Let's say there is an `Account` which is abstract base with some additional features like `Inbox` and two implementations `User` and `Device`. Of Course each of it's underfeachures will require some models.

```
Account
+--- Account.cs
+--- AccountController.cs
+--- Inbox
|        +--- Inbox.cs
|        +--- InboxController.cs
|         \--- Message.cs
+--- Device
|       +--- Device.cs
|        \--- DeviceController.cs
+--- User
        +--- User.cs
         \--- DeviceController.cs
```

That structure clearly has a naming conflict between namespace (folder name) and class (model name). I could easily solve first conflict by changing name of main feature `Account` to something more fancy like `Identity` but that still leaves two other (`User` and `Devices`) conflicts unsolved. Do i always need to find 'better fancy name' for each feature to avoid this problem ?

Keep in mind that i want to follow `folder-by-feature` structure, so creating new folder/namespace only for models is not an option.

Comment: Why not call them AccountModel.cs, InboxModel.cs and etc.

Comment: Those guidelines are no rules, you can break them if there´s a good reason to do so. However be aware that they exist for some reason and breaking them may lead to confusion in your team.

Comment: What about changing namespace's names (folder) like:
AccountDir -- InboxDir -- UserDir ??

Comment: @kamentk That would make sense, but personally i feel like that will be a bit messy. Name by itself (f.example `User`) screams that it is an model and adding suffix to it feels unnecessary and annoying. In addition i haven't seen many project which did that. So there have to be an alternative solution.

Comment: @RizkiDPrast That breaches the guideline, do not use abbreviations.

Comment: Simply use plural naming for the namespaces: The User class is then `MyApplication.Accounts.Users.User`

Answer (score 1):

The guidelines are actually called "Framework Design Guidelines". They are intended to be used by people who write libraries for others to use. They are guidelines, it is not required that you follow them. They essentially make clear what a user of your code would expect, not what you have to do.

On the same page that you link to is the guideline "CONSIDER using plural namespace names where appropriate". Following that would solve most of your problems.

StyleCop has a guideline to not create namespaces with fewer than five types in them.

Your specific problem could be solved by calling the namespace accounts and placing all your classes in that. Adding new namespaces only if it adds value.

Comment: That would make sense in `Accounts` namespace. But `Devices` feels counter intuitive. There is only one `Device` not `Devices`. But that's the best suggestion so far. 

StyleCop feels like good solution as well... but when you consider that 3 files from `user` + 3 from `devices`... may stack up quite fast. On top of that i feel like you should put files in the same folder if they are related to each other in both way. Relation between `Account` and `User` or `Device` is one sided thus having it in one file feels wrong.

Comment: It is a stronger and broader rule, read [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one/)